# htaccess send status error if FireFox and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, redirect, http-status-codes

Is there a way of redirecting all Firefox users **IN CURRENT DIRECTORY**, to a root error page ("/error.php"), and possibly displaying the status code of **417**

Here is my code so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Firefox.*$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* /error [R,L=417]
```

But it just just causes a server error from the current directory, can anyone help???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server error is quite possibly a too many redirects.  I'd add a second condition:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !/error
```

This will give it a page to look for to stop redirecting.

Comment: I might also run an [OR] operator after that one, and add the same line looking also for !/error.php